# Can't run intel power gadget

Tags: intel, skylake

First time posting here. I'm trying to monitor my CPU activity with the Intel power-gadget tool, that can be found on [Intel's web site](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20).

As the Readme file said, I execute the following lines

```
make
./power_gadget -e 1000 -d 10
```

I obtain the following error :

> RAPL not supported, or machine model 406e3 not recognized. Init failed!

Googling my issue didn't bring me any answer. Any clue about the reason of this issue ?

The CPU I am using (Skylake i7-6600U @2.60GHz) should be supported right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your CPU supports the required RAPL features.

The power gadget doesn't support your CPU though: the RAPL initialisation code is table-driven, and it doesn't know about Skylake CPUs (or even Broadwell). It only knows about Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge and Haswell (and even then, not all Haswell CPUs)...

Comment: Thank your for your quick and precise answer. I'll try to use other tools then.

Answer (score 1):

The power gadget hasn't been updated in a while for Linux (current version 2.5, but on OSX and Windows the current version is 3.0.x) - but you can use `turbostat --debug` to see a lot of the same information, including per-core RAPL measurements, etc. Here's a [man page](https://www.mankier.com/8/turbostat), but the man page on your system is more likely to be up-to-date.